# Why do we put $\mathrm{d}x$ in the integral?

Tags: integration, infinitesimals

Firstly, we studied that integration is always with $\mathrm{d}x$.
But in physics, I have seen this thing

$$V(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
$$\mathrm{d}x = V(t)\ \mathrm{d}t$$
Then here he adds the integration
$$\int\mathrm{d}x = \int V(t)\ \mathrm{d}t$$
Here I did not understand how to enter $\int$ without $\mathrm{d}x$.
Here I wonder what this is $\mathrm{d}x$,

is that true :
$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}t}
=∫\mathrm{d}x = x \,?$$

Please help me about everything you mentioned.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: You may have taken a course for which you are unprepared. You have to make peace with $dx$ in calculus. It may seem like a step backward to retake calculus but in the long run you will need it if you are pursuing a degree in science or engineering.

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $dt$ is an “abuse of notation.”  However, the results it produces can be justified through an application of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: This discussion is pointless. If he doesn't understand what $dx$ is then I doubt he understands that multiplying by it doesn't make sense for whatever reason.

Comment: Because we sometimes want to clarify with respect to which variable we integrate: What is $\int f(x,y)$ to you? Apart from this "what is $dx$?" is probably the most popular-pointless MSE question.

Comment: You have to read a lot( At least I Read a lot to understand this topic, Historical significance was also important) , Hence, Even If someone answers this question, I highly doubt it will satisfy you, Instead Reading about the topic by yourself would be a very good idea

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. It sounds like you'd like to know$$\int dx=\int1dx=x+C.$$

Answer (score 6):

To answer the question of your title, the reason we use $dx$ as part of the notation for the integral is because integral is related to *sums* of the areas of very thin vertical triangles of very small width.  Such an area is height times width $dx$.  Leibniz originally introduced the symbol $\int$, which is an elongated $S$ because $S$ is the initial letter of the word "sum" (or its equivalent in Latin or French).  More precisely, we partition the interval of integration on the $x$-axis into subintervals of very small length $dx$ and then take the corresponding sum.

To answer your additional questions, there is of course nothing special about the letter "x".  If we think of the line as the $t$-axis, we would denote the corresponding partition length $dt$, and write the integral as $\int_a^b f(t) dt$, instead.

To answer your question about replacing $dx$ by $dt$ in the integral, note that one can further subdivide the subintervals of length $dx$ into, say, $N$ smaller subintervals of length $dt$ so that $dx= N\,dt$ or $\frac{dx}{dt}=N$, and then the corresponding sum would involve $\frac{dx}{dt} dt$ in place of $dx$.  This corresponds to the change of variables formula in integrals.

The mathematical formalisation of such "very small subintervals" involves infinitesimals; you may want to look up some questions under the tag [infinitesimals](/questions/tagged/infinitesimals).

Comment: Integral formalisation only involves infinitesimals if you want it to

Comment: @FShrike, I was talking about the mathematical formalisation of "very small subintervals" rather than formalisation of integrals.